# I want to make my query in efficient way, I want to know what can I do to make it shorter or Any other way to do the same query?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, mysql-workbench

This is my Table

```
create table EmpTable (
 id int,
 task varchar(10),
 startDate varchar,
 endDate varchar
)
```

Here I am inserting my (id, task, starttime, and endtime

```
insert into EmpTable
select
1,'Task A', '2018-01-10 10:00:00', '2018-01-10 12:00:00';

insert into EmpTable
select
2,'Task B', '2018-01-10 11:30:00', '2018-01-10 16:00:00';

insert into EmpTable
select
3,'Task C', '2018-01-10 08:30:00', '2018-01-10 09:00:00';

insert into EmpTable
select
4,'Task D', '2018-01-10 09:00:00', '2018-01-10 15:00:00';

insert into EmpTable
select
5,'Task E', '2018-01-10 08:00:00', '2018-01-10 20:00:00';
```

used this to update the table

```
UPDATE EmpTable
SET starttime = '2018-01-11 9:00:00', endtime = '2018-01-11 9:30:00'
WHERE id = 2;


select * from EmpTable;

select *
from EmpTable as t1, EmpTable as t2
where t1.id = 1 and t2.id = 2;
```

this is my case which I am using for getting the details whether any slot getting overlaps or not.

```
select
case when
(t1.starttime between t2.starttime and t2.endtime) or
(t1.endtime between t2.starttime and t2.endtime) or
(t2.starttime between t1.starttime and t1.endtime) or
(t2.endtime between t1.starttime and t1.endtime)
then
'yes'
else
'no'
end as OverLapping
from EmpTable as t1, EmpTable as t2
where t1.id = 1 and t2.id = 3
```

Comment: Never, ever store timestamp values in `varchar` column. Just don't

Comment: MySQL or Postgres? Don't add tags for databases not involved

Comment: Instead of a CASE expression you can use `(t1.starttime, t1.endtime) overlaps (t2.starttime, t2.endtime)` which returns `true` or `false`

Comment: Your INSERTs could be made much shorter (to a single INSERT) by using a standard `VALUES()` clause